# Best way to reset a ruby on rails project

Tags: ruby-on-rails, code-cleanup

We have a ruby rails project which we normally get from our enterprise github repository. Recently, I've added dependencies that for some reason breaks my other projects that are not related to the one I was working on. My questions are

1. Does "bundle install" saves the dependencies globally? or can it behave like the npm to install on current project?
2. Can I undo "bundle install" by using "bundle clean --force"? after doing this and running "bundle install" again it doesn't to make any changes (not showing "Installing" instead it's say "Using"
3. I tried removing the the version of ruby since I found out that runing "bundle install" creates a directory /usr/share/rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.2@ruby_test_setup_engine/. But my issue was still there.

I also tried deleting the project folder and cloning it again but since
/usr/share/rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.2@ruby_test_setup_engine/ was created it didn't do anything at all.

Comment: "or can it behave like the npm to install on current project" - yes, it can. The setting is called `path` https://bundler.io/man/bundle-config.1.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure what kind of issues you are facing. but based on your question here is the details:

1. Does "bundle install" saves the dependencies globally?

- No it's not saves globally, it's saved specific to project and more specific to gemset you are using.

2. Can I undo "bundle install" by using "bundle clean --force"?

- No, this command just cleans up unused gems in your bundler directory.
- But you can undo your bundle via `rvm gemset empty`.

3. Removing gem directory won't help as it will create as soon as you run `bundle install` command.

Another way to reset you gemset is remove your `Gemfile.lock` and copy from original source and re run `bundle install`.

Hope this info will helps.

Comment: Don't remove `Gemfile.lock`, and especially on legacy projects. In this case bundler will build new dependencies tree. The consequences are unpredictable

Comment: That's true but you can copy paste original gemfile.lock from source before applying bundle install

Comment: "and more specific to gemset you are using" - bundler doesn't have gemsets. Are you thinking of RVM gemsets?